# iCloud Drive: My files can't be found on my iPad

Tags: icloud, numbers

I have 200go on my iCloudDrive and all my Documents folder is on the cloud.

On my iPad, with the Files app, I am able to browse in the folder hierarchy in Documents but ultimately the folders are not sync. Some files are missing, some folders also...

Why? What should I do?

Comment: So if you go into your iCloud Drive on your Mac (I'm assuming that's the other device), you can see a Documents folder with Numbers files within it?

Comment: I don't have my Mac with me, but I think the folder Numbers is directly in the Drive. The issue seems to be that the files are not sync... so far I have just used the Drive on my Mac only.

Comment: Please see edit also!

Comment: if you go to icloud.com on a browser (and log in with the same icloud login you are using on the mac and on the iPad) do you see the same files you have on the Mac in the "Numbers" folder? if yes, then the problem lies in the iPad sync, if no, the problem is in the Mac sync

Comment: The files are not in the iCloud website.